# Which REGEXP to use

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would suppose this can be best done with regexp, as that's probably the shortest way, but anything else as a suggestion is also good.

Say, I have a string in PL/SQL, and want to capitalize every Nth character if its small, and lower if its capital. For example, every fifth letter.

I'd want to examine the possibilities to achieve that.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a fun exercise but does it have a real-world application? Also: I don't think regular expressions are a good solution since one can't do any kind of string conversion (e.g., `LOWER()`, `UPPER()`) on a backreference.

Answer (score 2):

Since I have nothing better to do on a Saturday night (after Dark Matter of course) I decided to challenge my brain a bit. So after learning that SQLFiddle is broken, I installed Oracle 11g R2 Express Edition on my computer to work this out... yeah, I'm really that bored.

Directly from a table:

```
drop table test;
create table test (nbr number, txt varChar2(26));

insert into test (nbr, txt) values (1,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
insert into test (nbr, txt) values (2,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
insert into test (nbr, txt) values (3,'ABCDEFGHIJklmnopqrstUVWXYZ');
insert into test (nbr, txt) values (4,'abcdefghijKLMNOPQRSTuvwxyz');

select
  nbr,
  (
    select
      listAgg
      (
        case subStr(subStr(t.txt,((level - 1) * 5) + 1,5),5,1)
          when upper(subStr(subStr(t.txt,((level - 1) * 5) + 1,5),5,1))
            then subStr(subStr(t.txt,((level - 1) * 5) + 1,5),1,4) ||
                 lower(subStr(subStr(t.txt,((level - 1) * 5) + 1,5),5,1))
          when lower(subStr(subStr(t.txt,((level - 1) * 5) + 1,5),5,1))
            then subStr(subStr(t.txt,((level - 1) * 5) + 1,5),1,4) ||
                 upper(subStr(subStr(t.txt,((level - 1) * 5) + 1,5),5,1))
          else subStr(t.txt,((level - 1) * 5) + 1,5)
        end
      )
      within group (order by level)
    from
      dual
    connect by
      subStr(t.txt,((level - 1) * 5) + 1,5) is not null
  ) as "newTxt"
from
  test t
;
```

Or you can use a PL/SQL function:

```
declare
  function inverseCase(
    txt varChar2,
    nbr number
  )
  return varChar2 as
    newTxt varChar2(254);
    txtSeg varChar2(254);
    segA varChar2(254);
    segB varChar2(254);
  begin
    for i in 0..floor(length(txt)/nbr) loop
      txtSeg := subStr(txt, (i * nbr) + 1, nbr);
      segA := subStr(txtSeg, 1, nbr - 1);
      segB := subStr(txtSeg, nbr, 1);
      newTxt := newTxt || case segB
        when upper(segB) then segA || lower(segB)
        when lower(segB) then segA || upper(segB)
        else txtSeg
      end;
    end loop;
    return newTxt;
  end;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(inverseCase('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',5));
    dbms_output.put_line(inverseCase('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',5));
    dbms_output.put_line(inverseCase('ABCDEFGHIJklmnopqrstUVWXYZ',5));
    dbms_output.put_line(inverseCase('abcdefghijKLMNOPQRSTuvwxyz',5));
end;
```

Both return the following output.

```
nbr newTxt
1   ABCDeFGHIjKLMNoPQRStUVWXyZ
2   abcdEfghiJklmnOpqrsTuvwxYz
3   ABCDeFGHIjklmnOpqrsTUVWXyZ
4   abcdEfghiJKLMNoPQRStuvwxYz
```

Which I believe to be the text you are looking for.

It's been a while and I forgot how much fun this website is when I'm bored!

Answer (score 0):

As one of options, you can check 5-th character using CASE statement

```
SELECT ( case
when SUBSTR(fieldname, 5,1) = upper (SUBSTR(fieldname, 5,1)) then lower (SUBSTR(fieldname, 5,1))
when SUBSTR(fieldname, 5,1) = lower (SUBSTR(fieldname, 5,1)) then upper (SUBSTR(fieldname, 5,1))
else SUBSTR(fieldname, 5,1) ) 5char
FROM YourTable
```

The problem will occur afterwards as you'll have to divide string on 3, change letter case and concatenate them back. This will be bulky. Or play around with REPLACE function, but again, as far as I know it does not work with particular character position, only with substrings by pattern, thus you will end up with dividing and concatenating again.

Regexp probably least painfull

That is if we limit transformation to be in SELECT statement only, no PL/SQL procedures